# Getting the same results for two different models in glm() in RStudio

Tags: r, glm

I'm new to the R tool and am having some trouble with the `glm()` function.
I have some data that I have showed below. When the linear predictor is just x, the `glm()` function works fine but as soon as I change the linear predictor to x + x^2, it starts giving me the same results that I got for the first model.
The code is as follows:

```
model1 <- glm(y ~ x, data=data1, family=poisson (link="log"))
```

> coef(model1)
> (Intercept)        x
> 0.3396339   0.2565236

```
model2 <- glm(y ~ x + x^2, data=data1, family=poisson (link="log"))
```

> coef(model2)
> (Intercept)        x
> 0.3396339   0.2565236

As you can see there's no coefficient for x^2 as if it's not even in the model.

Comment: Is x just an indicator and only takes values of 0 or 1?

Comment: no not an indicator

Comment: Oh yeah just noticed you didn't wrap the x^2 in the `I` function. If you do does that change the output at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lm` and `glm` functions have a special interpretation of the formula (see `?formula`) which can be confusing if you are not expecting it. The intended usage of the interface is `(w + x)^2` means `a*w + b*x + c*w*x + d`! If you wish to suppress this you need to use the literal function, `I`.

```
model2 <- glm(gear ~ disp + I(disp^2), 
    data = mtcars, family = poisson (link = "log"))
coef(model2)
#  (Intercept)          disp     I(disp^2) 
# 1.542059e+00 -1.248689e-03  6.578518e-07
```

Put another way, `I` allows you to perform transformations in the call to `glm`. The following is equivalent.

```
mtcars1 <- mtcars
mtcars1$disp_sq <- mtcars1$disp^2
model2a <- glm(gear ~ disp + disp_sq, 
    data = mtcars1, family = poisson (link = "log"))
coef(model2a)
#   (Intercept)          disp       disp_sq 
# 1.542059e+00 -1.248689e-03  6.578518e-07
```

Comment: so gear ~ x + I(x^2) is the same as gear ~ x + x^2

Comment: `I` means literally square x and create a new linear predictor for it, and don't do any special interpretation of the `^2` part

Comment: You can also use `poly(disp, 2, raw=TRUE)` or `poly(disp, 2)` (the latter fits an orthogonal polynomial model that is computationally stabler and has statistical advantages but whose parameters are harder to interpret)